# identification vertical bundle and fiber product

Tags: differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ a vector bundle. I've seen that a vertical vector field on E is a section of $\pi_1:E\times_M E\rightarrow E$, but I thought  that it was a section of $\pi|_{VE}:VE\rightarrow E$, where $VE:=\ker T\pi\subset TE$ is the vertical tangent bundle. Then my question is: is there a diffeomorphism between $E\times_M E$ and $VE$ that identify those spaces? Is it the same for vertical 1-form? 
I found it in Libermann, Symplectic Geometry and Analytical Mechanics. Thank you very much

Comment: You should add the definition of $VE$ to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the isomorphism is the vertical lift
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rcl}
Vl_E:E\times_M E&\rightarrow& VE\\
(u_x,v_x)&\mapsto&\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}(u_x+tv_x)
\end{array}
\end{equation}